# Inverse Lorentz transformation and Doppler effect

Tags: special-relativity

In relativistic Doppler effect if the frequency of light source in S-frame is n(n is the proper frequency ) if an observer in S'- frame moving with velocity v measures the frequency of the light source is n'(using  Lorentz transformation). If the same event occurs in s'-frame (source is rest) we take "n' " as proper frequency and apply "v=-v" in above expression (inverse L.T) to find out " n "(where n is the observed frequency) for the 2nd case. My question is that in first case we take "n" is proper frequency (event is rest w.r.to s-frame) and " n' " observed frequency. If we choose inverse L.T to the first relation then does the frequency changes to observed frequency and vice versa or in both L.T and Inverse L.T proper frequency always remain as proper frequency. Please clarify my doubt.

Comment: You need to show your work. For instance, the Lorentz transformations require that the frames coincide. It will also depend upon where you're considering a longitudinal or a transverse doppler shift.

Comment: Regarding the Lorentz transform - or boost - in the $xt$ plane, namely, $x^{'}=\gamma(x-vt)$ and $t^{'}=\gamma(t- \frac{vx}{c^{2}})$, if you get the sign of the velocity correct in the Lorentz transform, then solving for the inverse Lorentz transform the sign of velocity will be correct, namely, $x=\gamma(x^{'}+vt^{'})$, and $t=\gamma(t^{'}+\frac{vx^{'}}{c^{2}})$. Since I have no idea what you did to want to change the sign of $v$ in the inverse transformation, the most common mistake is you didn't ensure the two frames coincided at $t^{'}=t=0$ - or have a common origin.